# How to solve - "Refused to display in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options to sameorigin" in ORO-CRM

Tags: localhost, magento-1.9, same-origin-policy, orocrm

If i try to create order from ORO-CRM getting error like,

[image]

How to solve the  X-Frame-Options to "sameorigin" issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing to do with ORO CRM. The domain your are requesting has header set so you cant use that URL inside an iframe. This is a security standard from almost all browsers to not allow show content on iframe if that header is being set. If that URL is from your own server you should match its origins in this case domains must match. Or you can try to remove x-frame-options from the headers.

Comment: Instead of iframe, what is the best practice to load as a new tab?

Comment: @zus please provide more details of what you are trying to do here

Comment: If I click create order in orocrm create new tab instead of iframe

Comment: @zus please provide with more context. Is this a default functionality or is a modification of some sorts? What have you tried to fix it?